# Tabs differences between TextBox and printed output

Tags: vb.net, printing

I'm building an order printing app, and I originally had a problem which I solved myself. I needed to set the tab locations in a `TextBox` to make the prices line up regardless of how long the item name was. I've left out the declarations below as they aren't relevant to my question, but I did this using:

```
Dim tabs() As Integer = {6, 85}
SendMessage(TextBox1.Handle, EM_SETTABSTOPS, 2, tabs(0))
```

which worked perfectly for the `TextBox` but when I connect to my Epson receipt printer and send the contents of `TextBox1.Text`, it interprets my tabs as normal sized ones - instead of two tabs at 6 and 85. I get default positioned tabs on the printer which mucks up the output.

Anyone know how I can set the tab locations on the printer as well (or maybe there's another way?) so that the printer output matches what's in the text box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the tab stops in your text box and the tab stops in your printer to the same number of characters or distance (depending on if you're using a proportional or fixed font).

Here's the command reference that should (mostly) work with your printer. The receipt printers do have a few extras like a cutter bar and downloadable images, however it should be close enough. https://files.support.epson.com/pdf/general/escp2ref.pdf You can also google for a tech manual for your specific printer which should have any specific codes.

The biggest problem is that you'll need to generate the entire document yourself and send it to the printer or print queue as a RAW formatted document, containing all the init sequences and control codes, and send it to the printer using RawPrinterHelper (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/322090).

It's messy, but the only way I know to get precise positioning, fast output and good text quality on dot matrix or thermal receipt printers.

You *might* be able to get by with setting the tab stops to the needed positions then saving the config if your printer supports this. the problem is that if you print using the standard Epson drivers, the printer get reinitialized and everything rendered as a bitmap instead of printing using the printer fonts and the settings you wanted.

You can also try the "Generic" printer driver, which has slots where you can configure the printer init code, but you'll still need to include any needed escape sequences for font changes/bold/etc. in your document.

Comment: Thanks for that. It's going down the right track and there seems to be an even simpler version of your solution. By adding the Windows.Devices.PointOfService reference in visual studio, supposedly you can simply use the posPrinter class which supports sending the esc/p commands directly from it. Only problem is i can only find code examples for C# and not VB

Comment: I'm not sure what the Windows.Devices class is actually part of. It doesn't seem to be listed in Visual Studio